# How do I create a SysHeader32 control in C#?

Tags: c#, header, controls

I am in the process of creating a custom control in C# for business process.  As a part of it, I need to create what looks like a header on a list view.

I've done this in the past using Visual c++ (6.0 :blush:).  I have not found a way to do it in C# (2.0).  Does anyone have any suggestions or links?

Thanks

Comment: Are you doing this in WinForms, WPF, or other?  Composing something that looked like a header on a list view would be pretty easy in WPF and not too bad in WinForms, but really it depends on how you are going to be using it.  Making something that looks and behaves like it shouldn't be too bad.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As someone who has done just this, I did not find it easy. My eventual solution and those I found on the web, was to wrap the Win32 SysHeader32 window in C#. (Wasn't easy.) Be familiar with Win32, and P/Invoke. [This](http://www.davidaferguson.com/HeaderControl.htm) was one of the sites that I found in my searches. Here's [another](http://www.codeguru.com/csharp/csharp/cs_controls/custom/article.php/c7475). (SysHeader32 C# control, etc., in Google turns up some results.)

Comment: Now if I can just add the system renderer to the second one!

Comment: Application.EnableVisualStyles();
was missing from the demo.  NOW it's just about perfect!

Answer (score 0):

There are lots of resources for creating custom resources out there: http://www.google.com/search?rlz=1C1CHMB_enUS318US318&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=C%23+custom+control

I recommend starting at MSDN, and branching out from there if you need more examples.